# Cannot find react component

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

It throw me Error: Cannot find react component `myTable`.. i have that react..

```
var myTable = React.createClass({

    render:function () {

        return(
            <div>
                <table  className="table scroll2" >
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Start Date</td>
                        <td>End Date</td>
                        <td>Hours</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {
                        this.props.list.map(function (item,i) {
                            return(
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{item.startDate}</td>
                                    <td>{item.endDate}</td>
                                    <td>{item.workInHours}</td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
angular.module('app').value('myTable',myTable);
```

and i call that with this :

```
 <react-component name="myTable"></react-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your component like this (notice the `Pascal Casing`):

```
var MyTable = React.createClass({ ... })
```

Use your component like this instead:

```
<MyTable />
```

As Justin has pointed out correctly, React class names must start with an upper-case letter, otherwise it will be interpreted as html tag. Thus, a lot of people follow [Pascal Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase).

From the official docs:

> To render a React Component, just create a local variable that starts with an **upper-case** letter

[JSX in Depth: HTML Tags vs. React Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)

Comment: React requires pascal casing for their React Components. Tag names that start with a lowercase are translated into HTML, while uppercase tag names are translated to React Components.  See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will update my answer!

Comment: Thanks guys its help me a lot :)

Comment: Guysssss i have still the same problem i was thinking i fixed but its still the same..i call it with that
 <react-component name="MyTable"></react-component>
..with 
<MyTable/>nothing happen i am sure its call with that i wrote but idk where is the problem ;xxx

Answer (score 0):

@Mario Tacke You're right with the exception that it HAS to be pascal cased if its a React element, otherwise it will be interpreted as a HTML tag element and not a react one.

More about it here https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/f1f4ba40816e7d7848ad